# problems with showing modal with jquery in Joomla

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, bootstrap-modal

I'm having a problem with showing a bootstrap modal with jquery in Joomla.

This is my php page page.php

```
<?php
/**
* @package     Joomla.Administrator
* @subpackage  com_helloworld
*
* @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
* @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
*/

// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
?>
<div id="actions">
    <div id='btn_group_container'>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
                <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

                <button type="button" id="add-sensor-button" class="btn btn-default" data-tooltip="tooltip"
                    data-placement='bottom' title='Aggiungi sensore'>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-scale" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>


                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="adding-sensor-form" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' id = "add-node-button" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Aggiungi nodo'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span>
            </button>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' id = "delete-node-button" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Cancella nodo'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus' aria-hidden='true'></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" id="sensors-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Id sensore</th>
            <th>Id nodo</th>
            <th>Grandezza misurata</th>
            <th>Unità di misura</th>
            <th>Batteria</th>
            <th>Azioni</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $sensors = $this->msg;

            foreach($sensors as $sensor){
                echo "<tr>
                    <td class=\"td-table\">".$sensor['0']."</td>
                    <td>".$sensor['1']."</td>
                    <td>".$sensor['2']."</td>
                    <td>".$sensor['3']."</td>
                    <td>".$sensor['4']."</td>
                    <td>
                        <!--<div class=\"btn-group\" role=\"group\" aria-label=\"...\">
                        <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default delete-btn\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"bottom\" title=\"Cancella sensore\">
                            <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\" aria-hidden=\"true\" onclick=\"deleteSensor(".$sensor['0'].")\"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>-->
                    <a href=\"index.php?option=com_sensorsmanager&view=deletesensor&id=".$sensor['0']."\">Cancella</a>
                </td>
            </tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

And this is my javascript page sensors.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add-sensor-button").click(function(){
            $("#adding-sensor-form").modal('show');
        });
});
```

I tried to show #adding-sensor-form modal with jquery but i couldn't . 
Any ideas?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

May be a jQuery Conflict
Change this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add-sensor-button").click(function(){
            $("#adding-sensor-form").modal('show');
        });
});
```

To

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#add-sensor-button").click(function(){
            $("#adding-sensor-form").modal({show:true});
        });
});
```

You can also show modal link this way

```
<a href="#adding-sensor-form" data-toggle="modal" class="btn">SHOW</a>
```